# Symfony2 constraint violation code definition on annotation

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, validation

Due to my project requirements, I must add a numeric code to each and every constraint violation, additional to the message. I have looked through the `ConstraintViolation` class and seen that it does indeed implement a [`$code`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/ConstraintViolation.php#L59) property, so that would be perfect for my needs... except there is no easy way that I could find to specify this code on the annotations.

For instance, looking at how either the [`Email`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/Email.php) constraint or its [parent class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraint.php) are implemented, there's no sign of that code anywhere, which makes it impossible for the annotations to define it.

The [validators](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/EmailValidator.php#L58) also inhibit the coder from setting the `$code`, as they don't pass the fifth parameter to `addValidation`, which is the code itself.

```
$this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array('{{ value }}' => $value));
```

So, my question is simple: am I missing something? Is there a way to set the constraint violation code via annotations that is not a pain? Ideally, I would like to do something like that:

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(code=400)
 * @Assert\Email(code=401)
 */
protected $email;
```

Editing `Constraint.php` to add the `$code` property (for being a valid annotation code) and all the constraint validators to pass the fifth parameter to `addviolation` seems a terrible idea!

Of course I could implement my very own validators, but what is the point on having a set of predefined validators then? It's just a one-line change.

Comment: Are you just trying to add an error number to each message, EG "user not found" becomes "404: user not found"?

Comment: @MrGlass Kind of, yes. I'm trying to populate the `code` property on a  `ConstraintViolation` object via annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a slight mistake. The code property in the validator is not the one you should look at. I think you should just create your own Validator constraints which are very simple classes:
https://github.com/symfony/Validator/blob/master/Constraints/Choice.php

And just toss in a public code property which then you can set via annotation or PHP. You dont need a new validation service, just that extra property. This propery will be added automatically when the constraint is constructed:

https://github.com/symfony/Validator/blob/master/Constraint.php

Here is more info on how to create the custom constraint:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: So basically you are suggesting to overload every other existing validator just to add a property to them? I'm sorry, but I don't really see that as a solution, specially when there is an unused `code` argument for `addViolation`.

Comment: Feras unfortunately I don't think that you're solution is feasible because if you write your own `Choice`, for example, then you also have to write your own `ChoiceValidator` so that you can pass in the `code` to the `addViolation` call so that it bubbles up to the `ConstraintViolation`.